# Use multithreading to increase the speed of web scrape

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, parallel-processing, beautifulsoup

I have a bit of a predicament.

There is a url with format : https://www.example.com/blahblah/moreblah.php?x=123456789&lang=en

As you can see, there is a unique identifier in the query (in this example UID = 123456789).  The script that I wrote will pull all the needed info for the page where x = 123456789.  I also placed the script into a loop and it increase the count of the UID by one (see below).  Only about 4% of all UIDs have data, but I have no way of identifying which UIDs contain data (I tried generating an xml sitemap without much luck - keep getting "site is not indexable")).

The existing code works, the problem is that this method will take too long.  I did some quick math and it will (in theory) take years to check each of the UIDs between 0 and 54 million (I have explored the site and found UIDs up to 53 million).

There are a couple of options in my opinion:
1. Multithreading/pooling (not sure how to do this).  Also, the way the loop is setup below, one loop has to finish in order for uid to increase by 1 before the next query can be executed (see line 20).
2. Find way to crawl the site and identify exactly which IDs need to be scraped and then limit the loop to those exact IDs.

I'm open to other suggestions too.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
uid = 0
def scrape (uid):
    while uid < 54000000:
        page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.example.com/blahblah/moreblah.php?x={}&lang=en".format(str(uid)))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        x = soup.find_all('div', id="container")
        x_string = str(x)
        try:
             parsing the x_string
        except:
            print "There is no data on this page"
        uid+=1

scrape(uid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading is not going to help here. Even if you can make multiple requests in parallel, you'd still need to make a total of 54MM+ HTTP requests. Handling these requests would place a massive load on the remote web server. (The 404 responses from the web server would easily amount to hundreds of gigabytes of data alone.) If you tried doing this, your crawler would probably be blocked from accessing the site long before the crawl finished.

You will need to find some other way to determine which IDs are valid.

Comment: Hi @duskwuff.  Thanks for the response.  It's interesting because I don't think I get 404 responses from the site.  Instead, any invalid uids will redirect to some sort of useless intermediate page.  I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Mick_eh Not really. Even if it isn't literally a 404 page, the HTTP redirect response contains a nontrivial amount of data, and generating that redirect takes a nontrivial amount of work for the web server. Multiply that by tens to hundreds of millions of requests, and you're looking at a lot of bandwidth and computation.